# Install Facebook SDK just for Facebook Mobile App Install Ads

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk, mono, ads

I'm trying to enable Facebook Mobile App Install Ads for my iOS app, I've installed Facebook SDK, the SDK itself is around 13MB. I'm just concerned about the size of my app, should I incorporate the whole SDK package just for one piece of code for Facebook Mobile App Install Ads? Or can I just import the required library?

As I don't want to increase my app size too much.

BTW, I use Mono Touch, so the whole Facebook.dll is around 10MB.

Thanks and regards,

Answer (score 3):

Facebook requires you to have the `Facebook iOS SDK` to use `Facebook Mobile Apps Install Ads`.

You need to add the following code in `applicationDidBecomeActive` method of your `AppDelegate` file

```
(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [FBSession.activeSession handleDidBecomeActive];  
    [FBSettings publishInstall:YOUR_APP_ID];
}
```

Check out [Facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/mobile-app-ads/) for full explanation.

Comment: Thanks Saravana. Do I need to call [FBSession.activeSession handleDidBecomeActive];  ? As it is not stated in the doco.

Comment: You dont have to use it. `[FBSettings publishInstall:YOUR_APP_ID];` is enough.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to do the same but with no success. Can some one give a step by step hint on how to do this in the right way? When my app call the FBSettings.PublishInstall method no exception is thrown. No install notificaiton are pushed to the developer FB appplication page.